# Applying DRY to a set of similar functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

Applying DRY is my biggest struggle. Can anyone help me create a single function that achieves the same as those 4 functions as well as how to call it for each .symbol?

```
$(".symbol:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass("gradient1");
})


$(".symbol:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass("gradient2");
})


$(".symbol:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass("gradient3");
})


$(".symbol:nth-child(4)").click(function(){
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass("gradient4");
})
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for improvements to working code. try asking on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes an index and assigns a click handler:

```
function applyNthClick( n ) {
   $(".symbol:nth-child(" + n + ")").click(function(){
     $("body").removeClass();
     $("body").addClass("gradient" + n);
   })
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
applyNthClick(1);
applyNthClick(2);
applyNthClick(3);
applyNthClick(4);
```

Or, if you know all the `n`s, you could make an array of them, and then map the function over it:

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach( applyNthClick );
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use the *index* of each element within the whole symbol collection

```
var $symbols = $(".symbol").click(function(){
     var symbolIndex = $symbols.index(this);
     $("body").removeClass().addClass("gradient" + (symbolIndex +1) );
 });
```

Reference: [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)